# How can i add text in the centre of the ARC in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, core-graphics

hello i am working on the pie chart application. i want to add the text in the middle of the arc. please show the image that i want show.

[image].

**i want to add the 100 and 250 in the arc with text the centre.**

here is my code

```
  int slicesCount = [self.datasource numberOfSlicesInPieChartView:self];

   for (int i = 0; i < slicesCount; i++)
   {
      sum += [self.datasource pieChartView:self valueForSliceAtIndex:i];
   }

   float startAngle = - M_PI_2-30;
   float endAngle = 0.0f;

   for (int i = 0; i < slicesCount; i++)
   {
      double value = [self.datasource pieChartView:self valueForSliceAtIndex:i];
      endAngle = startAngle + M_PI*2*value/sum;
      CGContextAddArc(context, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
      UIColor  *drawColor = [self.datasource pieChartView:self colorForSliceAtIndex:i];
      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, drawColor.CGColor);
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
       NSString *str=[arrValue objectAtIndex:slicesCount];
       CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 54, 63, [str UTF8String], str.length);// **how can i get X and Y coordinate**
      CGContextStrokePath(context);
      startAngle += M_PI*2*value/sum;
   }
```

plese help.
Thanks

Comment: I would consider using a third party library (such as CorePlot) for the graph instead of drawing the CoreGraphics code yourself. With CorePlot this would be rather easy.

Comment: i had completed 90% of my work i just want to calculate the middle of the arc so i can add text at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could calculate the center of the slice using the formula:

```
...
endAngle = startAngle + M_PI*2*value/sum;
labelAngle = endAngle - startAngle;
labelX = centerX + radius * cos(labelAngle);
labelY = centerY + radius * sin(labelAngle);
...
```

And then draw text in this point (note that these are coordinates of the center of the label).